# SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 49

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

**Error:**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 49
> at JSON.parse ()
> at parse (C:\Users\goktu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Flipkart\node_modules\body-
> at C:\Users\goktu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Flipkart\node_modules\body-parser
> at invokeCallback (C:\Users\goktu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Flipkart\node_modu
> at done (C:\Users\goktu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Flipkart\node_modules\raw-bo
> at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\goktu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Flipkart\no
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
> **Code:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const env = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

// Environment variable or you can say constants
env.config();

// MongoDB connection
// mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.kgufv.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.kgufv.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
    ).then(() => {
    console.log('Database connected');
});

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use('api', userRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

I'm new to coding, I think there is a problem with the body-parser library, I don't understand, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Its mean your request contains an invalid try to parse it with this online tool to find the problem

[enter link description here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu)

Also to avoid handling body parser errors yourself
I recommend using this middleware

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-body-parser-error-handler